# How are the following arrows displayed without an image?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a mockup here

http://jsfiddle.net/yug3Q/1/

If you click on a date you get forward and back arrows.  These do not appear to be images I would like to know how they are rendered.

Comment: This is how you can render an arrow without an icon: 
li.dropdown-submenu::before {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    border-top: 7px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 7px solid transparent; 
    border-left:7px solid #CCC;
    border-right-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    position: absolute;
    top: 9px;
    left: 90%;
}
li.dropdown-submenu::after {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    border-top: 6px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 6px solid transparent; 
    border-left:6px solid white;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 90%;
}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the CSS you'll notice the following line:

```
background-image: url(../img/glyphicons-halflings.png);
```

So, those buttons are indeed images.
`glyphicons-halflings.png` is an image file that contains lots of different images, and a particular image is chosen using the `background-position` property.  Such as:

`background-position: 14px 14px;`

From the [twitter bootstrap page on these icons](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#icons):
**Built as a sprite**
Instead of making every icon an extra request, we've compiled them into a sprite—a bunch of images in one file that uses CSS to position the images with background-position. This is the same method we use on Twitter.com and it has worked well for us.

Answer (score 0):

They are images that are part of a CSS [Sprite](http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/img/glyphicons-halflings.png).